# powershell HttpListener http file server

Tags: .net, file, powershell, http, httplistener

I'm trying to create a basic Powershell script to share files through http, I've copied the code from some samples I've found on internet.
My code is more or less like this:

```
$listener = New-Object Net.HttpListener
$listener.Prefixes.Add("http://+:8000/")
$listener.Start()

$response.Headers.Add("Content-Type","text/plain")
$buffer = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes((GC (Join-Path $Pwd ($context.Request).RawUrl)))
$response.ContentLength64 = $buffer.Length
$response.OutputStream.Write($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)
$response.Close()
$Context.Response.Close()
$listener.Stop()
```

I'm able to get the file, but it's not downloaded into binary, for example when I try to download a Zip file, new/downloaded file is bigger than original. I guess that has been transformed in ascii.
How can I preserve original file format?

I guess that I should replace the following lines, but what are the right ones to allow me get the files in binary format?

```
$response.Headers.Add("Content-Type","text/plain")
$buffer = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes((GC (Join-Path $Pwd ($context.Request).RawUrl)))
```

I just one to have a basic http file server to allow me get some 'zip', 'iso' files..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think this happens because if the contenttype in the response headers : you are setting it to text/plain. To use a binary representation set it to application/octet-stream

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is waaaaaaay overkill for an answer, but questioner did not post usable code and I didn't know how to make a PowerShell file server with HttpListener.  So, below is example code that makes a working Powershell file server with HttpListener.  Ultimately, the answer to the original question is `ContentType="application/octet-stream"`.  That delivers generic binary data to the requester.

```
$VerbosePreference="Continue"
Clear-Host
$Continue=$true
$Listener=[System.Net.HttpListener]::new()
$Listener.Prefixes.Add("http://+:80/")
$Listener.Start()
while ($Continue) {
  $Context=$Listener.GetContext()
  Write-Verbose $Context.Request.RawUrl
  if ($Context.Request.QueryString.HasKeys()) {
    $Continue=$false
    $Context.Request.QueryString.Keys | ForEach-Object { "$_ = $($Context.Request.QueryString.GetValues("$_"))" }
  }
  else {
    if ($Context.Request.Url.Segments.Count -eq 1) {
      $Content=[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("<html><body>Hello World</body></html>")
      $Context.Response.ContentType="text/html"
      $Context.Response.ContentEncoding=[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
      $Context.Response.ContentLength64=$Content.Length
      $Context.Response.KeepAlive=$false
      $Context.Response.StatusCode=200
      $Context.Response.StatusDescription="OK"
      $Context.Response.OutputStream.Write($Content, 0, $Content.Length)
      $Context.Response.OutputStream.Close()
      $Context.Response.Close()
    }
    else {
      if ($Context.Request.Url.LocalPath.EndsWith(".zip")) { $Context.Response.ContentType="application/octet-stream" }
      else { $Context.Response.ContentType="text/plain" }
      if (Test-Path -Path ("C:"+$Context.Request.Url.LocalPath.Replace("/","\"))) {
        $Content=Get-Content -Encoding Byte -Path ("C:"+$Context.Request.Url.LocalPath.Replace("/","\"))
        $Context.Response.ContentEncoding=[System.Text.Encoding]::Default
        $Context.Response.ContentLength64=$Content.Length
        $Context.Response.KeepAlive=$false
        $Context.Response.StatusCode=200
        $Context.Response.StatusDescription="OK"
        $Context.Response.OutputStream.Write($Content, 0, $Content.Length)
        $Context.Response.OutputStream.Close()
        $Context.Response.Close()
      }
      else {
        Write-Warning "File not found."
        $Content=[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("<html><body>File not found.</body></html>")
        $Context.Response.ContentType="text/html"
        $Context.Response.ContentEncoding=[System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8
        $Context.Response.ContentLength64=$Content.Length
        $Context.Response.KeepAlive=$false
        $Context.Response.StatusCode=404
        $Context.Response.StatusDescription="File not found"
        $Context.Response.OutputStream.Write($Content, 0, $Content.Length)
        $Context.Response.OutputStream.Close()
        $Context.Response.Close()
      }
    }
  }
}
$Listener.Stop()

#http://localhost/
#http://localhost/temp/filename.zip
#http://localhost/temp/filename.txt.log
#http://localhost/?x=y  # This (or something like it) will make the listener quit.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `GC` to read file content. GC(Get-Content) is used to read text files with options to specified encoding.

Use `FileStream` or others that read binary file content.

Comment: It's enough replace    $HRes.Headers.Add("Content-Type","text/plain")
    $Buf = [Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes((GC -Encoding Unknown (Join-Path $Pwd ($HC.Request).RawUrl)))      By this line ? 
    $Buf =  [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes((Join-Path $Pwd ($HC.Request).RawUrl) )

Comment: From version 6 you can use GC with `-AsByteStream`

Comment: Or you can use `[System.IO.File]::OpenRead`